# (Reference Recommendation) Spectral Measures and Integration

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory

My basic reference is Pedersen's Analysis Now, where he used the concept of spectral measure and integration just for a short section. I try to find more applications and theories on that matter. However, I have been able to. It is interesting as Vector Measure has probably received more attentions.

In any case, any good reference on spectral measure and integration from an operator point of view?